# Не находит объект Contains и ContainsKey c#

Tags: c#, коллекции

Есть 4 коллекции:

```cs
Stack<trialClass> collectionTrial;
Stack<string> collectionTest;
Dictionary<trialClass, testClass> dictionaryTr;
Dictionary<string, testClass> dictionaryStr;
```

Заполняю первую коллекцию:

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    trialClass temp = new trialClass(arrayNames[rnd.Next(0,9)], arraySubjects[rnd.Next(0, 9)], rnd.Next(0, 100));
    collectionTrial.Push(temp);
}
```

Вторую заполняю с помощью ToString() переопределенного

Ключи для 3 коллекции берутся из элементов первой коллекции

Ключи для 4 коллекции берутся из элементов второй коллекции

Суть проблемы:
При использовании Contains для стека не находит элемент через объект, но находит через строку:
Пример:

```cs
trialClass first = coll.collectionTrial.Peek();
first = new trialClass(first.NameOfExam, first.Subject, first.CountOfTrials);
string second = first.ToString();
trialClass third = new trialClass(first.NameOfExam, first.Subject, first.CountOfTrials);
string fourth = third.ToString();
bool result1 = coll.collectionTrial.Contains(first);
bool result2 = coll.collectionTest.Contains(second);
bool result3 = coll.dictionaryTr.ContainsKey(third);
bool result4 = coll.dictionaryStr.ContainsKey(fourth);
```

Результат выполнения:

```
result1 - false
result2 - true
result3 - false
result4 - true
```

Не понимаю почему так.

Answer (score 0):

Вы получаете ссылку на объект `trialClass` типа из `coll.collectionTrial` и записываете ее в переменную `first`:

```
trialClass first = coll.collectionTrial.Peek();
```

Хорошо. Следом, Вы сразу же записываете в эту же переменную ссылку на абсолютно новый объект:

```
first = new trialClass(...);
```

Естественно, в `coll.collectionTrial` этой ссылки нет, и `coll.collectionTrial.Contains(first)` возвращает `false`.

Comment: Необходимо искать объект не по ссылке, а по значению, как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Методичка говорит так: 2. При поиске элемента обратите внимание на то, что искать нужно сами элементы (содержимое), а не ссылки на них. 
Например:
//запомнили в first ссылку на первый элемент
Person first = ts.collection1.First; 
//запомнили в first содержимое первого элемента
Person first = new Person(ts.collection1.First.Name, ts.collection1.First.Age) ;

Comment: @Игорь Какая "методичка"? Это, вообще, что?

Comment: Учебное задание, рекомендации к выполнению

Comment: @Игорь переопределите equals и gethashcode в вашем классе trialClass